# Need help with architecting a solution for product add ons

Tags: architecture

We are looking to build Add on products for our company. we want to have options of adding on additional products on existing products as we dont want to creating new products for combination of products.

For example

if i order a pizza i can have addon of extra cheese or extra topping or i would choose one without any addons. And there could be only specific type of addons for a particular type of pizza. And i can have more than one add on for that pizza.

So we need to associate a product with a group of Products(Addons) so only these products(Addons) are only available as addons.

My thought process was to create a 2 custom objects

1. Addon Group - (Name)
2. Addon Group Detail (name, Product - Lookup, AddOn Group - Master Detail)

And then have Lookup on Product to Addon Group.

I also a VF page to add products into Quotelineitems, here once i have selected  the product to be added to quoteline, i will need to have the option of choosing the addons for that product which would be a multi picklist so i can add multiple addons.

I also should be able to report on the addons that have been used. I understand the reporting on multipicklist is a pain.

So can someone suggest a better way to execute this need.

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you use Junction Object here?

Comment: @TusharSharma Can you explain?

Comment: Use Junction between Product and Add on. So that one product have multiple Addon and one Addon can be used with multiple products